# XAMARIN Bluetooth не работает connect

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth

Делаю коннект через Блютуз. Нашёл вот такой код в методе `OnCreate`:

```
BluetoothSocket _socket = null;
//System.Threading.Thread listenThread = new System.Threading.Thread(listener);
System.Threading.Thread listenThread = new System.Threading.Thread(Listener);
listenThread.Abort();

buttonConnect.Click += delegate
{
    myConnection = new BluetoothConnection();
    myConnection.getAdapter();
    myConnection.getDevice();
    _socket = myConnection.thisDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    myConnection.thisSocket = _socket;
    myConnection.thisSocket.Connect();
    listenThread.Start();
};
```

Но выдаёт ошибку на строке:

```
_socket = myConnection.thisDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
```

Что это может быть?

Все разрешения на блютуз выставлены.

Comment: Как вы думаете, сама ошибка не столь важна, главное на какой строке она возникает?

Comment: Я думаю, что строка, на которой выдаётся ошибка, может безошибочно сработать, только если две предыдущие выполнились с ненулевым результатом (то есть реально получили адаптер и девайс). Нужно проверить их значения. И еще - хорошо бы, чтобы Вы добавили в вопрос саму ошибку, которая возникает. А, кстати, третья от ключевой строки строка (new BluetoothConnection()) тоже теоретически могла вернуть null. И еще: если это выполняется в эмуляторе, то допишите это в вопрос. Там наверняка в эмуляторе как то надо блютус настраивать.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы. Да, так всё и оказалось.
Вот ошибка.
[image: Ошибка]

Вот null по myConnection
[image: null]

Тестирую я всё на реальном устройстве Xiaomi Redmi 4A

Да действительно. Плохо отрабатывала вторая строка getDevice();

Я неправильно понимал connect. Это видимо среди тех устройств которые уже присоединены к моему телефону. А я думал, что это происходит опрос окружающих устройств в момент нажатия кнопки.

Спасибо за комментарии, они же ответы.
Не знаю как принять ответ? Куда нажать чтобы ответ был принят?